# Render sqlite output into template file, using bash script

Tags: bash, sqlite, templates, sed

I have `template`-like file, with some simple HTML in it.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>stackoverflow.com</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/master.css" type="text/css" media="screen" title="no title" charset="utf-8">

    </head>
    <body id="container">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="5" cellpadding="5">
        <tr>
            <th>Field 1 Label</th>
            <th>Field 2 Label</th>
            <th>Field 3 Label</th>
        </tr>

        <!-- ...dynamically generated content from other file should go here... -->
        <!-- ...instead of this template tag... -->
        ${sqlite_html_output} <!-- this is a placeholder I want to use -->

    </table>


    </body>
</html>
```

The file I want to render into this template, will be the output of **sqlite** query contained in the following function:

```
function generate_report() {

    sqlite3 -batch database.db <<- "end_of_message"
        .mode html
        .output o.html # <-- this is the name of generated output file
        select field1,field2,field3 from tbl;
    end_of_message

    #..here I want to use `sed` to embed content of o.html file, into my template
}
```

So in my `generate_report` function, I want to use sed to render that `o.html`
file, into my template, in place of that `${sqlite_html_output}` `template-tag` placeholder.

Would that be possible?

Comment: Can you use some other placeholder instead of `${sqlite_html_output}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
sed '/\${sqlite_html_output}/{r o.html
    d;}' template_file
```

It should search for a line matching `${sqlite_html_output}` and, when matching it, insert text read from `o.html` then delete content of line (i.e. `${sqlite_html_output} <!-- this is a placeholder I want to use -->` in your example).

Line break [is mandatory](https://superuser.com/a/456264/330163).

Comment: Is there some way to lowercase the content of  that `o.html`, before insertion, in one go?

Comment: Read text does not pass by `sed` pattern space, so we can't modify it on-the-fly. I don't know any way to read from standard input with `sed` `r` command, so I don't see any one-line solution. The easiest I see is a prior lowercase conversion of your file: `tr "[A-Z]" "[a-z]" < o.html > o_lowercase.html`, then reading from this `o_lowercase.html` file.